# Does Entityframework 7 support Oracle 12

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am working asp.net 5. I have installed Entityframework 7.
I am not able see code first approach. I have to connect oracle 12g.
Is it that ef 7 is not supporting oracle 12g. Any workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no public information from Oracle about support for EF7 (Ef Core)

There is a issue tracking this here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4293

Comment: Someone from Oracle wrote into the issue and provided this response: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4293#issuecomment-193400778  "The Oracle .NET team is evaluating EF7 support, but we have not
announced any timing.

The community can vote for the Oracle EF7 feature request here:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:39:105422858407495::NO::P39_ID:28241"